# NSIS NSD_CB_SelectString Wrong Value Selected

Tags: nsis

The DropList is being set to "TEST A" when I'd expect "TEST".

Does the NSD_CB_SelectString do a contain?

```
Name test
OutFile tester.exe
!include nsDialogs.nsh
XPStyle on
Page custom MyPage
Page instfiles

Function MyPage
    nsDialogs::Create 1018
        Pop $0
    ${If} $0 == error
        MessageBox MB_OK "Error"
        Abort
    ${EndIf}

    VAR /GLOBAL droplist

    ${NSD_CreateDropList} 0% 0 25% 12u ''
        Pop $DropList
    ${NSD_ONCHANGE} $DropList DropList_OnChange
        ${NSD_CB_AddString} $DropList "TEST A"
        ${NSD_CB_AddString} $DropList "TEST"
        ${NSD_CB_AddString} $DropList "TEST1"
    ${NSD_CB_SelectString} $DropList "TEST"

    nsDialogs::Show
FunctionEnd

Function DropList_OnChange
    ${NSD_GetText} $DropList $0
    MessageBox MB_OK "$0"
FunctionEnd

Section ''
SectionEnd
```

If I change the NSD_CB_SelectString = "TEST1" then that does work correctly.

Comment: I did find a work around for this issue, before the select I moved the value to be selected to the top of the list but still wondering if I'm doing something else wrong in the first place.

Answer (score 2):

`NSD_CB_SelectString` works correctly because it

> **Searches** the list of a combo box for **an item that begins with** the
> characters in a **specified string**.

Read https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/cb-selectstring for details.

Here is nsDialogs-style macro suitable for your task:

```
!ifndef NSD_CB_SelectStringExact
!define NSD_CB_SelectStringExact "!insertmacro _NSD_CB_SelectStringExact "
!macro _NSD_CB_SelectStringExact CONTROL STRING
  !insertmacro _LOGICLIB_TEMP
  SendMessage ${CONTROL} ${CB_FINDSTRINGEXACT} -1 `STR:${STRING}` $_LOGICLIB_TEMP
  StrCmp $_LOGICLIB_TEMP -1 +2
  SendMessage ${CONTROL} ${CB_SETCURSEL} $_LOGICLIB_TEMP 0    
!macroend
!endif
```

Add this macro to your .nsi-script or (preferably) into header file (e.g. nsDialogsEx.nsh).

Then replace `${NSD_CB_SelectString} $DropList "TEST"` string with `${NSD_CB_SelectStringExact} $DropList "TEST"` in your script

Comment: Both `NSD_CB_SelectString` and this macro are not case sensitive.

Comment: This looks like it is correct but please add `!ifndef NSD_CB_SelectStringExact` + `!endif` around the define and macro so it can be added to nsdialogs.nsh in the future without breaking things...